# Flask: wait until file will be stored by send_file command

Tags: python, flask, sendfile

By POST request I am going to let client store generated file to his local HHD by executing send_file() command. Here is the code:

```
def send_file_to():
    try:
        file_name = store_user_list()
        send_file(file_name, as_attachment=True, conditional=True)
        script_message = "File has been provided"
    except Exception as e:
        script_message = "File sending Error: " + str(e)
    return render_template('result.html', result_message=script_message)
```

unfortunately, it doesn't store file. Only if I change the script to:

```
       return send_file(file_name......
```

But I would like to get back on result.html page in any result. The command above leave me on the same page where I pressed the button "Download File".

Should I check any other event in @app to catch when download is finished?

Can you please help me understand the workflow that let me have required behaviour.

Comment: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/api/#flask.send_file is used to return a file to the client, not to save a file at all

Comment: @azro that exactly what I am trying to - return file to the client (store on his local hdd)

Comment: ow that is what you meant by "store a file", that isn't what the codes do, it just serve a content, then the client do what he want

Comment: So I don't know how to do it, but for sure you need a `return send_file()` to give the user the file, then idk how to redirect just after

Comment: @azro I updated my original question. I understand that I did something wrong and need advice how to fix it

Comment: You need to return the output of send_file in the try block or return the error in except block